# Why does dynamically adding a scrollbar pseudo-class to an iframe cause the browser to crash?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

1.add a new iframe in html:

```html
<iframe id="iframe-box" onload=onloadcss(this) src="..." style="width: 100%; border: medium none; "></iframe>
```

2. Add the following js code in the html:

```
function onloadcss(iframe) {
        let idoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        let style = idoc.createElement("link");
        style.href = "/public-style.css";
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        idoc.head.appendChild(style); 
  }
```

3.The content contained in the above css file is:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,::-webkit-scrollbar,::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    display: none;
}
```

4. Press F12 to open the console, press `ctrl+shift+c` or select the dom selector in the upper left corner.

5. Mouse over the iframe and the browser crashes 100% of the time.

[Demonstration of the operation of 4 and 5 steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBJ6n.png)

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o84ax.png)

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fwx6av?file=index.html

I don't understand why this is happening, all I have to do is change the above code to one of the following forms and it works fine:

1. add inline styles directly to `chicken-soup/index.html` nested by the iframe.
2. Add external css references directly to `chicken-soup/index.html` nested in the iframe.
3. Dynamically add the style dom into the head of the iframe.

None of these cases will cause the browser to crash.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-eretyk?file=index.html

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have found a bug in Safari and your question is a good minimum example for a bug report, so I can only suggest filling a bug report

You don’t mention which browsers you have tested this in, I’m guessing that it is Safari or Chrome from the CSS.

Apple bugs can be raised at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Report a Chrome bug https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315

It would be worth testing this in a few more browsers, including making a Firefox version of the test, so you can narrow down the issue to a single browser, or check to see if it effects all WebKit based browsers.